# Модальные окна открываются все одновременно

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap

Изучаю реакт и делаю страницу, на которой отображаются все картинки из файла json, при нажатии на каждую отдельную картинку должно открываться модальное окно с каждой конкретной картинкой. У меня открываются все вместе, перекрывая друг друга. Как можно исправить это?

Вот мой код:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';

export default function Portfolio() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ persons: [] });
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3000/portfolio-data.json").then((res) => {
      const persons = res.data;
      setState({ persons });
    });
  }, [setState]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="portfolio-wrapper">
        {state.persons.map((person) => (
          <>
            <Card
              style={{ width: "18rem" }}
              className="portfolio-card"
              onClick={handleShow}
            >
              <Card.Img variant="top" src={person.src} className="card-pic" />
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{person.title}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>{person.desc}</Card.Text>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>

            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
              <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>{person.title}</Modal.Title>
              </Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Body>
                <Image src={person.src} fluid />
              </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
          </>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Показ всех модальных окон зависит от одного значения `show`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что вы написали модальное окно  внутри цикла `map`.

```
<Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
   <Modal.Header closeButton>
       <Modal.Title>{person.title}</Modal.Title>
   </Modal.Header>
   <Modal.Body>
        <Image src={person.src} fluid />
   </Modal.Body>
</Modal>
```

Для решения просто напишите модальное окно за пределы цикла

```
   {state.persons.map((person) => (
      <>
        <Card
          style={{ width: "18rem" }}
          className="portfolio-card"
          onClick={handleShow}
        >
          <Card.Img variant="top" src={person.src} className="card-pic" />
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>{person.title}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>{person.desc}</Card.Text>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </>
    ))}

    <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
         <Modal.Title>{person.title}</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
         <Image src={person.src} fluid />
      </Modal.Body>
   </Modal>
```

И не надо так писать отображения модального окна. Сохраняйте кликнутый элемент в стейте, чтобы показать его внутри модального окна за пределы цикла.

Правильно будет вот так:

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ persons: [] });
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [personState, setPersonState] = useState();

  const handleShow = () => setShow(!show);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then((res) => {
      const persons = res.data;
      setState({ persons });
    });
  }, [setState]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="portfolio-wrapper">
        {state.persons.map((person) => (
          <>
            <Card
              style={{ width: "18rem" }}
              className="portfolio-card"
              onClick={() => {
                handleShow();
                setPersonState(person);
              }}
            >
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{person.name}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>{person.website}</Card.Text>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          </>
        ))}
        <Modal show={show} onHide={() => setShow(false)}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>{personState?.username}</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <span>{personState?.email}</span>
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-bird-i8e6w?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @daryalewy удачи.